# Save XML file at custom location

Tags: c#, path

I'm a very beginner with `c#`.

I write a little `XML` converter. In the debug mode saves my xml files under bin/debug.
I use:

```
XmlWriter xw = XmlWriter.Create("Filename.xml")
```

When I compile the code and run it, the xml are not saved.
What can I do to ensure that the xml is stored at a particular path?
The save Location path comes from a form as a string

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to combine the path and the xml file name, then use `XmlWriter` to write xml element:

```
string pathName = Path.Combine(location, "Filename.xml"); // location is the string from your form.
using (var xw = XmlWriter.Create(pathName))
{
    xw.WriteStartElement("myxml");
}
```

Comment: thank you! I have now done so: using (XmlWriter xw = XmlWriter.Create(savepath+"/filename.xml", writersettings))

Answer (score 0):

XmlWriter creates a new XmlWriter instance using the filename and XmlWriterSettings object. (Not saving the file!)

When you have the xml you can save it using System.IO:

```
File.WriteAllText(saveLocationPath, yourXML);
```